# Me imprime de manera errrada el json en php

Tags: php, json

Estoy tratando de traer los datos de una bd en mysql, me trae el ultimo dato que haya sido ingresado a la bd, pero no me trae todos los datos

```
<?php 
    include('conexion.php');
    $json = array();
    $link = conectarse();
    $select = "SELECT * FROM peliculas";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($link,$select);
    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        $json['peliculas'] = $registro;
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
    echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no es $json[] = $registro;?

Comment: Yo ya habia intentado de esa forma, el unico cambio que obtengo es que se me imprima esto 
{"0":"4","idPeliculas":"4","1":"Operacion rescate","Nombre":"Operacion rescate","2":"fasfdsfs","Sipnosis":"fasfdsfs","3":"2","Calificacion":"2","4":"sadfsd","Duracion":"sadfsd"}

en vez de esto 

{"peliculas":{"0":"4","idPeliculas":"4","1":"Operacion rescate","Nombre":"Operacion rescate","2":"fasfdsfs","Sipnosis":"fasfdsfs","3":"2","Calificacion":"2","4":"sadfsd","Duracion":"sadfsd"}}

Comment: Si intentaste eso, pulsa el boton [edit] y cuentanos que paso.

Answer (score 2):

Veo dos problemas, el primero que estás sobreescribiendo los resultados y en la variable `$json`siempre vas a tener el último registro.
prueba poniendo esto:

```
  $json['peliculas'][] = $registro;
```

Otro problema es que estás utilizando `mysqli_fetch_array`para recuperar el resultado sin indicarle el modo en el que quieres el resultado, por lo que por cada registro te devuelve un array asociativo y numérico a la vez duplicando los registros. Esto puede causar problemas a la hora de convertirlo a `json`.

Prueba cambianod la línea así:

`while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))`

Aquí te dejo tu código modificado:

```
 <?php 
    include('conexion.php');
    $json = array();
    $link = conectarse();
    $select = "SELECT * FROM peliculas";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($link,$select);
    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        $json['peliculas'][] = $registro;
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
    echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    ?>
```

Aquí más información sobre  [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) y [mysqli_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array)

**EDITO POR EL COMENTARIO**

Para depurar los posibles errores en la formaciónde `json` es muy útil la  función [json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-last-error-msg.php) usándola del siguiente modo:

`echo json_last_error_msg();`

Por ejemplo es común obtener el siguiente error:

> Caracteres UTF-8 mal formados, posiblemente codificados de forma
>   incorrecta

Esto sería solucionable definiendo en tu código el charset de la base de datos del siguiente modo:

`mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');`

Comment: Ahora ya no me muestra nada, e intente quitandole los corchetes pero obtengo solo el ultimo registro nuevamente

Comment: Hola @JulianFelipe, he editado la respuesta en base a tu comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Estas sobreescribiendo el dato en cada recorrido del bucle:

```
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    $json['peliculas'] = $registro;
}
```

prueba a darle índices diferentes:

```
$i=0;
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    $json[$i] = $registro;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi, hice un cambio en el codigo, fue este :

```
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $json['idPeliculas'][] = $registro['idPeliculas'];
    $json['Nombre'][] = $registro['Nombre'];
    $json['Sipnosis'][] = $registro['Sipnosis'];
    $json['Calificacion'][] = $registro['Calificacion'];
    $json['Duracion'][] = $registro['Duracion'];
}
```

Comment: Pero esto te va a crear un JSON donde los elementos no están realmente relacionados/ordenados como en la base de datos.

Comment: Efectivamente, solvente ese problema guiandome de otro y es este

                while ($registro[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
          $json= json_encode($registro);
      }